# Java reverse engineering tool

Tags: decompilation, java, byte-code

I'm getting started on Java reverse engineering but I can't find a great tool. I'm currently using JD-Gui to decompile it.

I've tried PNF's JEB which is really perfect but it's only for Android stuff. Is there anything similar for standard Java ? Preferably free because JEB costs a lot for someone who doesn't use it a lot...

Some features I'd like would be decompilation of course but also class / variable renaming, find usage, and standard features you could find in IDEs..

Answer (score 3):

I develop [Recaf](https://github.com/Col-E/Recaf), a free Java bytecode editor. Recaf currently supports *most* of what you're looking for in the current release *(Decompile via [CFR](http://benf.org/other/cfr/), class/member renaming, a verbose search feature, and contextual actions on the decompiled code)*. Right now it's going through a rewrite which will include even more of the features you're looking for.

If you have any questions / feedback I'd appreciate if you'd check out the project.

---

Also if you're reverse engineering obfuscated samples check out [Java-Deobfuscator](https://github.com/java-deobfuscator/deobfuscator).

Answer (score 1):

The Bytecode viewer is a great tool because it has different decompiler that you can try to use.

https://bytecodeviewer.com/